# ActiveRecord: update_all shows query in debug log, but doesn't execute in DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got the following update query running in a function called by a `before_destroy` callback in a Rails model:

```
Annotation.joins(:annotation_groups)
  .where({'annotation_groups.group_id' => self.id})
  .update_all({qc_approved: false}) if doc.in_qc?`
```

(I've also tried the following simpler version to see if another angle works: `self.annotations.update_all({qc_approved: false})`)

Both generate the below SQL query in "Server development log" (debugging in RubyMine):

> `UPDATE "annotations" SET "qc_approved" = 'f' WHERE "annotations"."id" IN (SELECT "annotations"."id" FROM "annotations" INNER JOIN "annotation_groups" ON "annotation_groups"."annotation_id" = "annotations"."id" WHERE "annotation_groups"."group_id" = 159)`

However, as far as I can tell, that SQL never causes a DB update, even though the destroy process afterwards works fine.  I can set a breakpoint directly after the statement and look at the database, and the `qc_approved` fields are still true.  However, I can copy and paste the statement into a Postgres console and run it, and it updates the fields correctly.

Is anyone aware as to what would cause this behavior?  Does `before_destroy` exist in its own strange alternate transactional universe that causes odd behavior like this?  What scenario would cause the SQL to show up in the server log but not make it to the DB?

Comment: Destroy (including callbacks) does run inside a transaction if that's what you're asking

Comment: Have a look for 'ROLLBACK' further down in the logs. ActiveRecord callbacks DO exist in their own transactional universe, and if the main delete fails all will be undone.

If you set a breakpoint directly after the delete you may find that the delete has failed, or if you have any after_destroy callbacks, check them. Etc. Etc.

Comment: I don't see a rollback.. after the above SQL, I see the actual DELETE call for deleting the Model's record, and then COMMIT and 200 OK.  Strangely, the delete afterwards in the same transaction works but the update does not.

Comment: Not sure how `...group_id' => self.id}` works for you - seems to error for me unless it's a feature of a newer version of AR. All you need though is `:id`. Also, you could remove those ugly curly braces. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the quick and helpful comments above confirming the nature of the callback inside the larger transaction, I figured it out.. despite the name, `before_destroy` was actually executing after dependent destroy calls, so that the joined `annotation_group` table row was destroyed before the `UPDATE` statement that relied on it was called in the transaction.

To be more specific, I added `:prepend => true` to the `before_destroy` definition so that it ran before the destroys as intended.